# How to install JOGL on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, jogl

I'm trying to run a program, which uses JOGL for its GUI, in Jason. I'm getting the following error:

```
    [CentralisedEnvironment] Error in Centralised MAS environment creation
net.java.games.jogl.GLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.java.games.jogl.impl.macosx.MacOSXGLContextFactory
```

I think the problem is that it can't find the `jogl.jar` file. Based on a number of tutorials I've found, I put it in the `/lib/ext` folder of my Java folder (`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext`).

After this didn't work, I set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to include the JOGL lib folder (I typed `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/.../lib` in a terminal, not sure if anything happened).

I've tried this with at least 3 different versions of JOGL and not one of them worked.

What am I missing?  Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is.  Sounds like you need to set the Java `classpath` variable.  Either that or you need to specify the path to the .jar file on execution using the `-classpath`or `-cp` flag (same thing).  I'd say this is what you need to do.

[This page](http://homepage.mac.com/kelleherk/iblog/C149402102/E1304178353/index.html) has a good description of where OS X looks for .jar files by default.

See the bottom of this [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and the [Oracle page on setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for general coverage of options on how to define the classpath.

Also check [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=956258) on using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.